# Huh no spatial info bah

Tags: solr

Hi I am new to using Solr 3.6.1. I am attempting a geospatial search using solr, whose index is imported from MySQL using DIH. I can see that there are lat & lng data (but not latlng) returned from the `*:*` query.

**Problem:** When I attempt a geospatial search, I get no results returned. I only get results when I increase the search distance `d` to a very large values like 100000, and the results returned contains no lat/lng data.

Could I have missed out something in the schema or data-config that prevented the geospatial data from being searched?

I would also like to sort according to ascending distance. I tried appending `&sort=geodist() asc` to the end of the query url but have an error `unknown query type 'asc'`. Thank you for all the help!! :)

**Geospatial Query:**

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/select?wt=json&q=*:*&start=0&rows=10&fl=*,score&fq={!geofilt pt=41.570015,-71.09061 sfield=latlng d=5}`

**Geospatial Query Results:**

```
{"responseHeader":
    {"status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{"fl":"*,score","start":"0",
    "q":"*:*",
    "wt":"json",
    "fq":"{!geofilt pt=41.570015,-71.09061 sfield=latlng d=5}","rows":"10"}},
    "response":{
        "numFound":0,
        "start":0,
        "maxScore":0.0,
        "docs":[]
    }
}
```

**Some results from `*.*`:**

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">517</int>
    <lst name="params">
    <str name="explainOther"/>
    <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    <str name="indent">on</str>
    <str name="start">70000</str>
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="hl.fl"/>
    <str name="wt"/>
    <str name="fq"/>
    <str name="rows">100</str>
    <str name="version">2.2</str>
</lst>
</lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="76270" start="70000" maxScore="1.0">
    <doc>
        <float name="score">1.0</float>
        <str name="id">2584854</str>
        <float name="lat">41.570015</float>
        <float name="lng">-71.09061</float>
    </doc>
```

**data-import**

```
query="select id, lat, lng,
    concat_ws(',', lat, lng) as latlng
    from listings"
```

**schema**

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>

<field name="latlng" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="lat" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="lng" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<dynamicField name="*_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />
```