# SolrQueryByDistance: kilometers or meters?

Tags: solr

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch states:

**NOTE: Unless otherwise specified, all units of distance are kilometers and points are in degrees of latitude,longitude**

As seems to be the case in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631969/huh-no-spatial-info-bah) question, I need to multiply my distances by 1000 before I get any results.

E.g.:

```
{!geofilt pt=52.375,52.38 sfield=geo d=2992}
```

Since we've coupled the latlong information with zipcodes, I can verify that the returned zipcodes are all in the same neighbourhood.

So, distance, what unit is it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an obvious mistake: The coordinates I was using for geofilt, were nowhere near the coordinates for my documents.